# Replace image tag by div with DOMDocument and return altered html

Tags: php, domdocument

In the following code, I'm trying to replace each image found in `$content` by some html. With `$dom->saveHTML($image)` I get the image html, but `str_replace` doesn't replace it. I don't know why.

```php
$content = '<div class="content"><img src="some-image.png"></div>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
    $i = $dom->saveHTML($image);
    $replacement = '<div class="test"><a href="#">some link</a><span>test</span></div>';
    $content = str_replace($i, $replacement, $content);
}
// $content should be altered with the previous edits.
return $content;
```

At the end, `$content` should return:

```php
<div class="content"><div class="test"><a href="#">some link</a><span>test</span></div></div>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Do not use str_replace. It's a DOM, we can use replaceChild.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
    $node = $dom->createElement("div");
    $frag = $dom->createDocumentFragment(); // create fragment
    $frag->appendXML('<div class="test"><a href="#">some link</a><span>test</span></div>');
    $node.appendChild($frag);
    $image->parentNode->replaceChild($node, $image);
}
```

It's HTML. The dynamic nature of HTML makes it very difficult to perform regex or string replacement correctly. However PHP allows dom manipulation via `DomDocument`. So select the images parentNode and replace the image with a div.

Updated it using `createDocumentFragment()`. This will create a DOM fragment in memory. You can appendXML (read HTML) to it as a string. Then you can append the fragment to the node.

Comment: @inwpitrust. As requested. However you should make this clear in your question from the start. Our answers here provided a solution to the question you've asked. Either post a new question or make the final result apparent in your original question.

Comment: "make the final result apparent in your original question." You mean that I should add the elements given in your response in my question? Isn't it redondant? Thanks for your help!

Comment: What I meant is that you've build your question in three steps. Just describe what you need in the end in the first place.

Comment: Ok I've edited my question with your advices. Do you know how can $content be altered with the edits previously done?

Answer (score 3):

The way to replace a **DOMNode** is to use the method `replaceChild` (`str_replace` is to deal with strings only):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$imgNodeList = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($imgNodeList as $imgNode) {
    $divNode = $dom->createElement('div');
    $textNode = $dom->createTextNode('test');
    $divNode->appendChild($textNode);

    $imgNode->parentNode->replaceChild($divNode, $imgNode);
 }
```

If the replacement is more elaborate than a div tag with text inside, you only need to build the replacement node in the same way (appending other nodes to it). To deal with attributes see http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createattribute.php

Comment: @inwpitrust: I have taken a look, now you have all elements to do it by yourself (see how I have added the text node to the div node).

Comment: Thanks! I've edited my question to reflect what I needed in the first place, can you give me some advice on how to return $content as an altered var?